# how to open Filedialog in desired directory

Tags: java, swing, filedialog

I have two buttons both open filedialog what i want both button should always open their related directories in filedialog  when they press.In my case filedialog keep the last open directory which i don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't name the used framework, but assuming, it's Swing, [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) has some constructors that allow to set the initial path:

```
JFileChooser(File currentDirectory)
      Constructs a JFileChooser using the given File as the path.
```

For [`FileDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) from the AWT framework, use a setter to set the directory *before* displaying the dialog

```
setDirectory(String dir)
      Sets the directory of this file dialog window to be the specified directory.
```